# Decalthon st100 making crying noise from back tyre

Tags: mountain-bike

I've bought a decalthon st100 bike and the back tyre is making a cry type sound. Feels like the noise is coming from axle but I'm not sure why exactly. Please help with some leads.

Video link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1itZJ-0WA5LcGQb9faa63aJLg5jmLsCX5/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Something is rubbing -- most likely one of the brake pads against the rim.

Comment: Need to isolate the source more - hang the bike off the ground somehow and spin the wheel and move around to spot the source location.   Mind the fingers !

Answer (score 2):

Having watched the video, it looks like the brake pad is not aligned with the rim.  The noise occurs when the white area (the manufacturers logo is probably slightly raised) on the tyre passes the brake pad.

You can check by slowly rotating the tyre and seeing if that area is rubbing.